# How do I display a variable image with a KV file?

Tags: python, image, kivy

I am trying to make a card game with Python and Kivy and can not get the card to display. So far, ChaseTheAce.deal pick a random card and removes it from the deck. I can not figure out how to pass the string from the card dict to the Image in the KV file. I'm new to Kivy and am having trouble with the IDs and what information matches with information from the PY file. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

## PY File

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import random
import numpy as np

cards = ['ace_spades', 'king_spades']
dict = {'ace_spades':'ace_of_spades.png', 'king_spades':'king_of_spades2.png'}

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass

class GameScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScoreScreen(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class ChaseTheAce(App):
    cardimagefile = StringProperty()
    def deal(self):
        mycard = random.choice(cards)
        cards.remove(mycard)
        cardimagefile = (dict[mycard])
    def build(self):
        return kv

kv = Builder.load_file("cta1.kv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ChaseTheAce().run()
```

## KV File

```
<GameScreen>:
    ChaseTheAce:ChaseTheAce
    name: "GameScreen"
    GridLayout:

        rows: 3
        Image:
            id: cardimage
            source: ChaseTheAce.cardimagefile #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            allow_stretch: True
        GridLayout:
            dealer:deal
            cols: 3

            Button:
                id: deal
                text: "Deal"
                on_release:
                    app.deal()
```

Edited to remove unrelated parts of the code.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]..

Comment: I removed everything that was unrelated to the image question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few errors in your example:

- You need a root layout that contains all the stuff of your app.
- You need a `ScreenManager` to manage your `Screens` (that you must put inside it).
- To access your `cardimagefile` property in your `.py` file, you have to use `self.cardimagefile`, otherwise you are just creating a new, different, local `cardimagefile` variable.
- To access your `cardimagefile` property in your `.kv` file, you have to use `app.cardimagefile`

Since I don't have your images, I added a `print` whenever the `source` of the `Image` is changing, and it works fine..

The py code:

```py
cards = ['ace_spades', 'king_spades']
dict = {'ace_spades':'ace_of_spades.png', 'king_spades':'king_of_spades2.png'}

Builder.load_file("cta1.kv")

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass

class GameScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScoreScreen(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class RootLayout(FloatLayout):  # create a root layout
    pass

class ChaseTheAce(App):
    cardimagefile = StringProperty()
    def deal(self):
        mycard = random.choice(cards)
        cards.remove(mycard)
        self.cardimagefile = (dict[mycard])  # the cardimagefile is not local needs self.
    def build(self):
        return RootLayout()  # you must return the root layout here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ChaseTheAce().run()
```

The kv code:

```py
<RootLayout>:        # you need a root layout
    WindowManager:   # that contains a ScreenManager
        GameScreen:  # that manages the screens
            # ChaseTheAce:ChaseTheAce  # you don't need this
            name: "GameScreen"
            GridLayout:
                rows: 3
                Image:
                    id: cardimage
                    source: app.cardimagefile #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                    allow_stretch: True
                    on_source: print(self.source)
                GridLayout:
                    # dealer:deal  # you don't need this
                    cols: 3

                    Button:
                        id: deal
                        text: "Deal"
                        on_release:
                            app.deal()
```

Comment: Do I have to Import RootLayout into my PY? What happens to the 'return kv'?

Comment: @Trippingbillies41 You have to import `FloatLayout` `from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout`. You still have to use the `Builder.load_file("cta1.kv")` line too. You don't need to assign it somewhere though... [Fixed it in my answer]

Comment: I made an edit with the error that occurs after I made your edits. Any ideas?

Comment: @Trippingbillies41 What do you mean "move off of the login screen"? There is no code for this!. The code I posted solves the problem of the code that you posted. And it works, so you can accept it as an answer. For other problems, you should create a different thread. Its not nice for the people that will see this, to have an ever changing question/answer... ;o)